How can I create editable and drawable grid cells in tldraw, similar to a spreadsheet?
I'm working on a project using tldraw and trying to create a grid-like interface where each cell can be used to draw or write inside it, similar to a spreadsheet. I want to integrate the drawing tools  so that users can either draw shapes, write text, or use other tools directly inside each cell.
UI for the cells
Is there a way to customize tldraw to constrain drawings to specific areas (like grid cells)?
I’m currently rendering each cell as a separate shape using tldraw, but this approach is causing significant memory consumption and performance issues. The page takes a long time to load and becomes sluggish when interacting with many cells.
I'm looking for a way to optimize the rendering of these cells so that the page is more responsive.
